# How to troubleshoot TensorFlow error “Restoring from checkpoint failed.”

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow, I have been using a trained model from a Git repository. The pre-trained model is saved in '../model/snapshot-38' directory. I have snapshot-38.index, snapshot-38.meta, snapshot-38.data-00000-of-00001 and checkpoint files here. I have my python script files and data in '../src' and I don't use any other location other than these in my code to save model.

```
def save(self):
    "save model to file"
    self.snapID += 1
    self.saver.save(self.sess, '../model/snapshot', global_step=self.snapID)
```

I am using Python 3.6, Tensorflow 1.12.2

I have backed these files and tried re-training using a different set of data and generating a new model output but aborted half way through.

I have then restored my pre-trained model files from the back up as before but from since then I am getting error "Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a mismatch between the current graph and the graph from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:" delete saved model

When I try either retrain or restore the model. Is there some temporary files that I need to remove ?? doubt if Tensorflow is trying to do something I am not aware, I don't really get an answer from any of the solutions in similar threads. Below is the detailed stack trace,

```
 as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:524: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:526: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:527: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:532: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
Validation character error rate of saved model: 10.624916%
Python: 3.6.10 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  7 2020, 19:46:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Tensorflow: 1.12.0
2020-06-26 00:53:20.161185: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
model DIR ---- ../model/
model latestSnapshot ---- ../model/snapshot-38
Init with stored values from ../model/snapshot-38
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1334, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1319, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1407, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1,1,512,71] rhs shape= [1,1,512,80]
         [[{{node save/Assign_15}} = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_5"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Variable_5, save/RestoreV2:15)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1546, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1152, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1328, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1348, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1,1,512,71] rhs shape= [1,1,512,80]
         [[node save/Assign_15 (defined at P:\Desktop\COSC428_ComputerVision\SimpleHTR-master\SimpleHTR-master\src\Model.py:141)  = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_5"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Variable_5, save/RestoreV2:15)]]

Caused by op 'save/Assign_15', defined at:
  File "main.py", line 145, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 140, in main
    model = Model(open(FilePaths.fnCharList).read(), decoderType, mustRestore=True, dump=args.dump)
  File "P:\Desktop\COSC428_ComputerVision\SimpleHTR-master\SimpleHTR-master\src\Model.py", line 53, in __init__
    (self.sess, self.saver) = self.setupTF()
  File "P:\Desktop\COSC428_ComputerVision\SimpleHTR-master\SimpleHTR-master\src\Model.py", line 141, in setupTF
    saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=1) # saver saves model to file
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1102, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1114, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1151, in _build
    build_save=build_save, build_restore=build_restore)
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 795, in _build_internal
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 428, in _AddRestoreOps
    assign_ops.append(saveable.restore(saveable_tensors, shapes))
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 119, in restore
    self.op.get_shape().is_fully_defined())
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\state_ops.py", line 221, in assign
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_state_ops.py", line 60, in assign
    use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3274, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1770, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1,1,512,71] rhs shape= [1,1,512,80]
         [[node save/Assign_15 (defined at P:\Desktop\COSC428_ComputerVision\SimpleHTR-master\SimpleHTR-master\src\Model.py:141)  = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_5"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Variable_5, save/RestoreV2:15)]]


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 145, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 140, in main
    model = Model(open(FilePaths.fnCharList).read(), decoderType, mustRestore=True, dump=args.dump)
  File "P:\Desktop\COSC428_ComputerVision\SimpleHTR-master\SimpleHTR-master\src\Model.py", line 53, in __init__
    (self.sess, self.saver) = self.setupTF()
  File "P:\Desktop\COSC428_ComputerVision\SimpleHTR-master\SimpleHTR-master\src\Model.py", line 153, in setupTF
    saver.restore(sess, latestSnapshot)
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1582, in restore
    err, "a mismatch between the current graph and the graph")
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a mismatch between the current graph and the graph from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:

Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1,1,512,71] rhs shape= [1,1,512,80]
         [[node save/Assign_15 (defined at P:\Desktop\COSC428_ComputerVision\SimpleHTR-master\SimpleHTR-master\src\Model.py:141)  = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_5"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Variable_5, save/RestoreV2:15)]]

Caused by op 'save/Assign_15', defined at:
  File "main.py", line 145, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 140, in main
    model = Model(open(FilePaths.fnCharList).read(), decoderType, mustRestore=True, dump=args.dump)
  File "P:\Desktop\COSC428_ComputerVision\SimpleHTR-master\SimpleHTR-master\src\Model.py", line 53, in __init__
    (self.sess, self.saver) = self.setupTF()
  File "P:\Desktop\COSC428_ComputerVision\SimpleHTR-master\SimpleHTR-master\src\Model.py", line 141, in setupTF
    saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=1) # saver saves model to file
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1102, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1114, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1151, in _build
    build_save=build_save, build_restore=build_restore)
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 795, in _build_internal
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 428, in _AddRestoreOps
    assign_ops.append(saveable.restore(saveable_tensors, shapes))
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 119, in restore
    self.op.get_shape().is_fully_defined())
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\state_ops.py", line 221, in assign
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_state_ops.py", line 60, in assign
    use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3274, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\rcs70\.conda\envs\tensorflow_opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1770, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a mismatch between the current graph and the graph from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:

Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1,1,512,71] rhs shape= [1,1,512,80]
         [[node save/Assign_15 (defined at P:\Desktop\COSC428_ComputerVision\SimpleHTR-master\SimpleHTR-master\src\Model.py:141)  = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_5"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Variable_5, save/RestoreV2:15)]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says this: `Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1,1,512,71] rhs shape= [1,1,512,80]`

This means that the dimensions of one of the tensors in the snapshot are different from the tensor in the model, in the snapshot it is `[1,1,512,80]` and in the model it is `[1,1,512,71]`.

Therefore, something is different. You have to load the snapshot on a model that matches **exactcly** the one it was saved from.

If I would have to guess, I would say that this is a multi-class classification model and that the number of classes the model was trained in (i.e. the snapshot) was 80, while now the model has been built to classify 71 classes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am pretty sure I did not modify the backed up model snapshot. But it is still complaining when I reloaded it, I haven't made any other changes to the code structure. Do you know if TensorFlow caches the model snapshot somewhere else?

Comment: I am not saying that you modified the snapshot, but the model onto which you are loading the snapshot.

Comment: You said: "I have backed these files and tried re-training using a different set of data and generating a new model output but aborted half way through." Would it be possible that in the new data the number of labels is different?

Comment: I did abort the re-training half way through because I realised that data set was not compatible. But in my understanding that shouldn't affect the original snapshot that I backed up?? I have deleted the files from that run ( snapshot-38.index, snapshot-38.meta, snapshot-38.data-00000-of-00001 and checkpoint file) and restored the original snapshot from back up. Sorry, I am new to TensorFlow and deep learning.

Comment: Figured out why.. As you mentioned somehow there were issues with the config. One of the 80 classes was missing from config file hence there were only 79 classes but model was trained with 80. Thanks for your time.